# Triangulate point

Tags: linear-algebra, triangulation

I am reading linear algebra and there is a problem involving hyperbolic curves that struggle with.

Three points $P_0=(0,0), P_1=(0,\frac{21}{4}), P_2=(0,\frac{25}{3})$.
A point is located $\frac{5}{3}$ units closer to $P_0$ than $P_2$, and $\frac{7}{4}$ units closer to $P_1$ than $P_0$. What is this points coordinates?

I have come to two hyperbolic curves between $P_0, P_1$ and $P_0, P_2$: $$(8y-21)^2-8x^2=7^2$$ $$(6x-25)^2-\frac{3y^2}{2}=5^2$$

However when I try to solve for the intersection all I get is a complicated fourth degree polynomial. I must be taking the long road to solve this or maybe my brain is fried today. Please help!

The book answer: $(3,4)$

Comment: Hi Erik. If I am not wrong you don't have a point as answer but a geometric place which would be the circle $$x^2+\left(y+\frac{12217}{492}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1295}{41}\right)^2$$ and this becomes from $$d_0=\frac53d_2\\d_1=\frac74d_0$$ eliminating by division $d_0$.

Comment: Thank you. I am hesitant to claim that the textbook is wrong, but I think this headache is one of those mythical occurrences where "THE ANSWER IN THE BOOK IS WRONG". But I am very happy to have verification by you :). Now my Friday can be peaceful again.

Comment: @ErikEriksson: You should provide the book's answer. (Put it into the body of the question, as comments are easily overlooked and can be hidden.)

Comment: @Blue I added the answer. Thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: @Piquito I plotted the hyperbolic curves in my graph calculator, and unfortunately I have to admit defeat, the book was indeed right. The intersections are points :(

Comment: @Erik Eriksson: I have truble with the meaning of "closer". So the two equations I gave you are not valid maybe.

Comment: @Piquito Since the chapter is about hyperbolic functions I assume "closer" means $||\vec{P_0P}|-|\vec{P_2P}||=\frac{7}{4}$